# Error in provider flutter context listen:false

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

So, I'm making an app of OTP login with flutter and dart and when I provide the pohone number it's shows an error

The code is this:

```
 void sendPhoneNumber() {
    final ap = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false);
    String phoneNumber = phoneController.text.trim();
    ap.signInWithPhone(context, "+{selectedCountry.phoneCode}$phoneNumber");
  }
```

The error it's when I'm in final ap, there shows this: "Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree."

Any idea what can i do to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem like you're forgetting to create an object

**Single**

```
Provider(
  create: (_) => MyModel(),
  child: ...
)
```

**Multi**

```
    runApp(
            MultiProvider(
              providers: [
                ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => myViewModel()),
                       ]
                      )
```